# Generate a new random number each time function is called in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I am trying to learn javascript, I am playing with a game that picks a random number.

I would like to have 2 functions, random and guess. Random generates a new number between 1-10. Guess is where it checks if the number was guessed, if not re-runs the random function and generates a new number to try.

```
var x;
function random(){
    let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    guess();
 }

function guess(x){
    if(x === 3){
        alert('you are correct!');
    }else{
        alert('try again');
        random();
    }
}

random();
```

This just alerts try again every time, i'm guessing because it's not generating a new number each time the function is called?

How can you create the random function so it generates a new number each time its called?

***** Correction, it appears to generate a new number but x is undefined within the guess function**

Comment: Your `guess` function expects the number as a parameter. Call it like `guess(3)`, or `guess(x)` with the random value. Also drop the global `var x`, you're not using that anywhere.

Comment: @Bergi that worked, I added guess(x) within the random function. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x` in the `guess()` is the `x` that gets passed to it as a parameter. I would remove the `var x;` declaration and pass a value when calling like `guess(x)`

```js
function random(){
    const x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    guess(x);
 }

function guess(x){
    if(x === 3){
        alert('you are correct!');
    }else{
        alert('try again');
        random();
    }
}

random();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `guess` function's signature says that it takes a parameter `x`, but you're not passing any value to the function when it's called, so it's assigning `undefined` to `x` when it runs `guess`, which will never equal `3`. You can take 2 approaches to fix this. First, you could make `x` a **global variable** by getting rid of the `let` where you define `x` in the `random` function and removing `x` from `guess`'s function signature, like so:

```js
var x;

function random() {
  x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  guess();
}

function guess() {
  if (x === 3) {
    alert(x + '- you are correct!');
  }
  else {
    alert(x + '- try again');
    random();
  }
}

random();
```

Or, you could use x as a **parameter** for the guess function by removing the `var x;` global declaration and passing `x` to `guess` when you call it in the `random` function, like so:

```js
function random() {
  let x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  guess(x);
}

function guess(x) {
  if (x === 3) {
    alert(x + '- you are correct!');
  }
  else {
    alert(x + '- try again');
    random();
  }
}

random();
```

I personally wouldn't even have a `random` function. I'd just define `x` within `guess` and call `guess` from within itself. And, I'd use [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) to make the randomness more readable. Here's how I'd do it:

```js
function guess() {
  let x = rando(1, 10);
  if (x === 3) return alert(x + '- you are correct!');
  alert(x + '- try again');
  guess();
}

guess();
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Note that the `return` statement would stop the execution of the function right then and there, so it wouldn't progress to the "try again" alert if the number was guessed correctly.

Comment: Thank you for all the info! Definitely helps me understand this better

Answer (score 1):

I have done some changes to your code. 
You have problem with the concept of function calling function. 
In real code it will kill your memory.. your function calls function the function not close and call the function again and again... and its fill the memory .

```
var x;
// flag correct will close the loop when you have right umber 
var correct = false;
function random() {
    x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    guess(x);
}

function guess(x) {
    if (x === 3) {
        alert('you are correct!');
        // if number is right flag is up 
        correct = true;
    } else {
        alert('the number is ' + x + ' try again');
    }
}
// loop until the number is right
while (correct != true) {
    random();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some detailed code that will help you understand how to run such a game in the browser.

See the comments for explanation of how it works (and search for information on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) to learn more about any particular topic.)

Happy coding!

```js
// Identifies HTML elements
const
  guessInput = document.getElementById("guessInput"),
  outputParagraph = document.getElementById("outputParagraph");

// Makes a global variable that all functions can access
let globalNum;

// Invokes the main function
playGame();


function playGame(){
  
  // Invokes the randomizer function and stores the result in the global variable
  globalNum = getRandomNumber();
  //console.log(globalNum);
  
  // Invokes the output function
  setOutput("Guess a number from 1 to 10");

  // Assigns a function that will be invoked whenever the user changes the input field
  guessInput.addEventListener("change", respondToGuess);  

  // Puts the focus in the input element
  guessInput.focus();
}


// Defines a listener function that can automatically see the triggering event
function respondToGuess(event){

  // Gets the `target` element of the event and stores it in a local variable
  const localReferenceToInputElement = event.target

  // The text of an `<input>` element lives in its "value" property
  const inputText = localReferenceToInputElement.value;

  // Tries to convert the text string to an integer (and store it locally as 'guess')
  let guess = parseInt(inputText);

  // If the conversion failed, changes the output accordingly
  if(!guess){ setOutput("Please enter a valid number"); }

  // If the number is out of range, changes the output
  else if(guess < 1 || guess > 10){ setOutput("Only numbers from 1 to 10 are allowed"); }

  // If the guess doesn't match the stored number, changes the output
  else if(guess !== globalNum){ setOutput("Try again..."); }

  // If we got this far, the guess was correct, so changes output and ends game
  else{
    setOutput("You guessed it!");
    reset();
  }
}


function getRandomNumber(){
  // Returns a random number into whatever function called this function
  const x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  return x;
}

function setOutput(outputText){
  // The text of a paragraph element lives in its `innerHTML` property
  outputParagraph.innerHTML = outputText;  
}

function reset(){
  // Clears the input and stops listening for changes
  guessInput.value = "";
  guessInput.removeEventListener("change", respondToGuess);
}
```

```html
<input id="guessInput" />
<p id="outputParagraph"></p>
```